# Determine if DT datatable is clicked in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Here is a working example of my best attempt to get table click event:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('table')),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      dt <- data.frame(a = 1)
      datatable(dt, rownames = FALSE, selection = 'none')
    })
    observeEvent(input$table_cell_clicked, {
      print(Sys.time())
    })}
))
```

The problem is that `observeEvent` reacts only if user clicks on the cell which differs from previously clicked. Is there a way to get event on any table click?

Comment: Since the output is ultimately a div on the webpage, I imagine you can use Javascript to catch a div click event.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it s may be helpful

Try add `callback` with `Shiny.onInputChange` 
and add smth which changed all time ( `rnd`)

smt like

```
   JS("table.on('click.dt', 'td', function() {
            var row_=table.cell(this).index().row;
            var col=table.cell(this).index().column;
            var rnd= Math.random();
            var data = [row_, col, rnd];
           Shiny.onInputChange('rows',data );
    });")
```

and then use it like :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('table')),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(data.frame(a = c(1,2),b=c(2,3)), rownames = FALSE, selection = 'none', callback = JS("table.on('click.dt', 'td', function() {
            var row_=table.cell(this).index().row;
            var col=table.cell(this).index().column;
            var rnd= Math.random();
            var data = [row_, col, rnd];
           Shiny.onInputChange('rows',data );
    });")
      )}
    )

    observeEvent(input$rows, {
      print(input$rows)
      print(Sys.time())

    })}
))
```

Then parse all `row` and `col` from  `input$rows`

PS. in datatables index start from 0 .

Comment: If your table is on several pages, input$rows[1] will refer to the row of the current page. To get the absolute row number in `observeEvent` use `input$table_rows_current[input$rows[1]+1]`, see https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html